# Can I return a string based on a value in the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

Consider the following query:

`SELECT operation, [...] FROM tableName`

The `operation` field will retrieve an integer from 1 to 4. What I would like to do is assign a string value to a variable in the SQL query, based on the integer value of `operation`.

If it were up to me, I would have a corresponding table that contained the name of each operation, in which case a `JOIN` would pick up the operation string. Unfortunately, I do not control the database.

I don't know if this is even something SQL can do, and I could certainly iterate over the returned data using PHP to perform this task instead, but it makes sense to do it all in one hit if possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try something kile this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
     operation
  WHEN 1 THEN 'OP1'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'OP2'
  WHEN 3 THEN 'OP3'
  WHEN 4 THEN 'OP4'
  ELSE
     'Unknown OP'
  END OperationName
  , 
[...] FROM tableName
```

Comment: +1 In this example it is better to use a simple case statement rather than a searched case statement as has been posted in the other answers

Answer (score 6):

```
select
  case when operation = 1 then
    '1st operation'
  case when operation = 2 then
    '2nd operation'
  else
    'Unknown operation'
  end operation_name
from tableName
```